# Which Hyperledger Fabric version is recommended 1.4 or 2.x

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I would like to know what is the recommended version of Hyperledger Fabric (1.4 or 2.x) or if it is 100% recommended to implement the most recent version, in this case 2.x.

This is because for obvious reasons 1.4 has more downloads and implementations for having more time published.

Greetings and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyperledger fabric 1.4 community support will finish in April 2021 (Service providers may provide support for longer). The recommendation is that you should start with Hyperledger fabric 2.2 which is the current LTS version or 2.3 if you want to try some of the newer capabilities